# 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'StdImageField'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use [django-stdimage](https://github.com/codingjoe/django-stdimage) to resize my picture but i'm getting this error `AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'StdImageField'`

Model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.db.models import Q
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField
from .validators import validate_file_size
from stdimage.models import StdImageField



    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
    
    
    
        picture = models.StdImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", validators=[validate_file_size], size=(256, 256))
```

Comment: Use `StdImageField` instead of `models.StdImageField`. That is not a field from `django.db.models`. You have already imported that by `from stdimage.models import StdImageField`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StdImageField` is not from *django* but from third party library i.e, `stdimage`. And, you have already imported it like:

```
from stdimage.models import StdImageField
```

So, simply remove *models*:

```
 class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    picture = StdImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", validators=[validate_file_size], size=(256, 256))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `StdImageField` belongs to the `stdimage.models` module, so you use it with `picture = StdImageFIeld(…)`, not with the `models.` prefix:

```
from stdimage.models import StdImageField

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    picture = StdImageField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        upload_to='images',
        validators=[validate_file_size],
        size=(256, 256)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

`StdImageField` is not part of Django's `models` API so calling `picture = models.StdImageField` won't work. You've already imported `StdImageField` so just change your model field to

```
picture = StdImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images", validators=[validate_file_size], size=(256, 256))
```